# Configure Paypal Sandbox ReturnURL with localhost

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to insert http://localhost:4000/api/myroute as returlURL
on https://developer.paypal.com.

Paypal displays this message :
We are sorry something went wrong while saving application please try again...

So, localhost seems be forbidden but the last week, it's was ok.

How can i enter localhost url ?

Please, do not answer me the 127.0.0.1 solution.

Answer (score 0):

"localhost" to PayPal's server, is themselves, so if they tried to redirect to http://localhost/whatever, it would just go right back to their own server, and that URL most likely wouldn't exist, and you'd end up with a 404 at the PayPal server.

If you want to test on your local server you're going to need to setup DNS to point some sort of a domain to your public IP address there, and make sure your web server is configured to answer to that domain as well.

For example, your site might be www.domain.com.  Lookup your public IP address there, and then create a DNS record for domain.com that points sandbox.domain.com to your public IP address there.

Then you can use http://sandbox.domain.com anytime you need to work with PayPal (or anything else) and it'll work the same as "localhost" is for you now, but 3rd party servers will be able to communicate with your application as expected.  This will also allow you to have other people on different networks test/demo the site with you.

Comment: so, can I use my etc/hosts file with www.sandbox.domain.com that point on 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: That might work, but I always recommend just doing it the way I mentioned above to be sure.

Comment: Stumbled upon this answer through Google. Just wanted to add that this is not how it works. They are not redirecting their own request, they are redirecting the user's browser to that URL, so localhost would redirect the user to their own machine and this is very much a desirable behavior if you are a developer integrating PayPal.

Comment: Some of it is affected and some of it isn't.  For example, if you're working with IPN or Webhooks you wouldn't be able to use "localhost".